# C++: Creating large memory mapped file freezes pc

Tags: c++, boost, freeze, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to create a large memory mapped file with data that I want to use in a project. I'm using Boost library for the mapped files and everything seems to run fine until I try to create a big file (>2GB). My computer only has 3GB of RAM, and during the creation of the file it freezes. Is there a way to create the file using small chunks of data and avoid the freezing of the process?

```
char p[20] = "test.raw";
boost::iostreams::mapped_file_params  params;
params.path = "test.raw";
params.new_file_size = sizeof(struct Rectangle) * data_size;
params.mode = std::ios_base::out;
boost::iostreams::mapped_file  file;
file.open(params);
struct Rectangle* dataMAP = (struct Rectangle*) file.data();
for(unsigned long long i=0; i<data_size; i++){
    dataMAP[i] = struct Rectangle(rand_float_array);
}
```

I'm running the program in 64-bit mode and have enabled /LARGEADRESSAWARE.

**UPDATE**

I'm currently trying to run a small example using the "Boost Interprocess" library but I cannot get it to run. This is my code based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602311/storing-vector-in-memory-mapped-file) answer:

```
std::string vecFile = "vector.dat";
bi::managed_mapped_file file_vec(bi::open_or_create,vecFile.c_str(), sizeof(struct Rectangle) * data_size);

typedef bi::allocator<struct Rectangle, bi::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager> rect_alloc;
typedef std::vector<struct Rectangle, rect_alloc>  MyVec;

MyVec * vecptr = file_vec.find_or_construct<MyVec>("myvector")(file_vec.get_segment_manager());

vecptr->push_back(random_rectangle);
```

But the compiler says that it could not deduce the template argument for '_Ty*' from 'boost::interprocess::offset_ptr'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you try to create memory mapped files that are smaller? How about at 1/2GB or 2GB?

Comment: It runs fine. I tried a 0.5GB and there was no problem. Something else I observed was that the memory usage was about 1MB and then suddenly everything stopped.

Comment: So if you create four 0.5GB files, it works fine?

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: If I create four, how can I link them? The Rectangle struct has some float arrays that are referenced in other parts of the project. Yes @CollinDauphinee I'm using Windows.

Comment: @TheShadow: Check the overall system memory usage and page fault delta of your process while it's frozen

Comment: Before crashing the process uses about 1MB then the whole OS freezes. I had to reboot after waiting for 20 minutes. Also it seems that the OS uses a process for "Compressed Memory" at the time of freezing.

Answer (score 1):

boost::iostreams calls the Win32 [CreateFileMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537) function behind the scenes [here](https://github.com/boostorg/iostreams/blob/develop/src/mapped_file.cpp#L302) ... this function gives you a view into the file. And note the zero values that boost is passing as `dwMaximumSizeHigh` and `dwMaximumSizeLow` arguments--it's asking for a mapped view into that *entire* huge file.

It looks like there are quite a few limitations with CreateFileMapping() listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366542.aspx). Note the part that says "The size of a file view is limited to the largest available contiguous block of unreserved virtual memory." ...so I think iostreams is actually asking your system to allocate a huge chunk of virtual memory, which evidently puts your system into a death spiral.

Since you're already using Boost, I'd give its [interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/interprocess.html) library a shot instead. It has good memory mapped file support, STL-like containers that can be mapped to an MMF, and it supports mapping smaller regions of that huge file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've updated the original question with problems I found when attempting to use boost interprocess.

Comment: @TheShadow I think your follow-up deserves its own separate question.

Comment: Allocating lots of virtual memory should not affect other programs, because each program has its own virtual address space.

Comment: In an ideal world, no it wouldn't affect other apps. But one process hammering the disk (a single, shared physical resource) with excessive paging (and causing the OS to swap out pages from every other process to accommodate its memory demands) will most definitely affect the performance of other processes and the overall system.