# Placement new inside placement new?

Tags: c++, memory-mapped-files, placement-new

I'm trying to setup memory mapped files with boost interprocess. The following class contains the mapped data & some mutex/condition variables.

```
struct trace_queue
{
    trace_queue()
        : parent_done(true)
        , sim_end(false)
    {}

    boost::interprocess::interprocess_mutex      mutex;
    boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition  parent_running;
    boost::interprocess::interprocess_condition  child_running;
    bool parent_done;
    bool sim_end;

    float data[12];   // Want to dynamically allocate this.
};
```

I create a file of size `sizeof(trace_queue)`, map it and then I instantiate the class into the mapped memory given to me by boost:

```
trace_queue * tq = new (addr) trace_queue;
```

This works fine. But my question is:

1. How can I dynamically allocate the `data` member pointer inside `trace_queue` instead of it having a constant size, such that the allocated memory still fits inside the memory given to me by boost?
2. What would be the new file size? `sizeof(trace_queue) + data_count*size_of(float) - sizeof(float*)`?

Comment: Make sure that you are executing the `new(addr) trace_queue` only from a single process, other processes that share the same mapped file must use `(trace_queue*)addr` instead, otherwise you are constructing your `trace_queue` several times.

Comment: @cmaster Yes I already do that, thanks.

Comment: Why not use a vector for data? Perhaps use the memory mapped file as an arena and then [allocate trace_queue and the dynamic members in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29602884/1460794)?